# NPM React peerDependencies error

Tags: reactjs, npm

I tried to install several npm modules related to React but I got a peerDependencies error. The versions seem ok to me:

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package react does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-autosuggest@3.3.1 wants react@^0.14.5
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-bootstrap@0.28.2 wants react@>=0.14.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-dom@0.14.6 wants react@^0.14.6
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-router-bootstrap@0.20.1 wants react@>=0.14.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-switch-button@1.1.1 wants react@^0.13.3
```

Doesn't react@0.14.6 satisfy all of:

- react@^0.14.5
- react@>=0.14.0
- react@^0.14.6
- react@^0.13.3

My package.json is:

```
    {
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "dependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.4.0",
        "babel-loader": "^6.2.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.4.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
        "history": "^1.17.0",
        "jquery": "^2.2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.0.0",
        "react": "^0.14.6",
        "react-autosuggest": "^3.3.1",
        "react-bootstrap": "^0.28.2",
        "react-dom": "^0.14.6",
        "react-router": "^2.0.0-rc2",
        "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.20.1",
        "react-switch-button": "^1.1.1",
        "webpack": "^1.12.11"
    }
    }
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: `13.x` is not compatible with `14.x` (according to `semver`).  See rules [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` [Allows changes that do not modify the left-most non-zero digit in the [major, minor, patch] tuple.](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-1-2-3-0-2-5-0-0-4), so `react@^0.13.3` does not match `react@0.14.6`.

It would however match any `0.13.x` version greater than or equal to `0.13.3`.

Comment: What I don't understand is that previously, I had react-switch-button@~1.1.1 successfuly installed along with react@~0.14.3…